# Invert svg image using css?

Tags: css, image, svg, css-filters

I'm trying to invert an image file with `.svg` extension using `css`. I know `.png` and `.jpg` files can be inverted using `css` `webkit` properties. I am new on `svg` images. Is it possible to invert `.svg` images using `css`?

I tried using

```
-webkit-filter:invert(1);
        filter:invert(1);
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Just style the SVG element directly

```
svg {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%); /* safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
          filter: invert(100%);
}
```

From IE9 and above you [can](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-img) use SVG in `<img src="" />` element.

```css
img { /* svg on an img tag */
  -webkit-filter: invert(.75); /* safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
          filter: invert(.75);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg" />
```

You can set the amount as percentage or as number as this [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/invert) says

> The amount of the conversion, specified as a `<number>` or a
>   `<percentage>`. A value of `100%` is completely inverted, while a value of
>   `0%` leaves the input unchanged. Values between `0%` and `100%` are linear
>   multipliers on the effect. The lacuna value for interpolation is `0`.